# How do I switch to a Modal Popup and identify elements in it using coded steps in Telerik

Tags: telerik

Scenario:

1. Launch a web page
2. Click on the Login button
3. A Modal Popup appears with username, password fields and a Sign In button

   Expected:

a. I would like to identify username, password and Sign In elements in the Modal Popup,

b. I would like to pass values to the username and password fields in the Modal Popup,

c. I would like to click on the Sign In button in the Modal Popup.

I wish to achieve a, b and c using coded steps. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code library on the matter: [Using r.a.d.window for a login form](https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-r-a-d-window-for-a-login-form).